# Page-Range: output hypen as en-dash in \autocite

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm trying to get `\autocite` to output `--` for the page-range, the same way Biblatex does it for the bibliography entries:

[image: Output]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-comp,
uniquename=mininit,
uniquelist=minyear,
firstinits=false,
backref=false,
hyperref=true,
useprefix=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887-891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Brushing teeth is expensive \autocite[883-890]{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\autocite[883--890]{Bli74}`.... :-)

Comment: @karlkoeller: Yeah sure, that's one way to do it. But I'm hoping for an automatic solution. Biblatex uses the command `\bibrangedash` to normalize dashes in the bibliography section, so it should also be possible to do the same with the in-text citations.

Comment: Of course I know what you want. But I don't know of an automatic solution ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit cheating, but as `\mkcomprange` normalizes a range you could try

```
 \setcounter{mincompwidth}{100000}%something large
 \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Cheating for sure, but it's a nice hack, so thank you ;) I'm still a bit baffled that with `biblatex` this is needed at all. It's such a basic feature. Is everyone else doing this manually with `--`?

Comment: Well make a feature request. Imho it would be neat to be able to have a command to normalize such input when needed on the tex side (the page range in the bibliography is normalized by biber, so this is a different case). As \mkcomprange shows the code is already there, it needs only an interface.

Comment: OK, good idea! Here we go: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/293

Answer (score 2):

Following the feature request https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/293 this has been implemented in `biblatex` 3.11 (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/674, it took a bit more than three years, but better late than never, I guess).

There is a new command `\mknormrange` that works similar to `\mkcomprange` from Ulrike's answer with the important exception that `\mknormrange` only normalises the ranges and does not compress them in any way.

`\mknormrange` has been added to the default postnote formats

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
```

so that the MWE from the question will now give an en-dash (`\bibrangedash`) without further modifications

[image: Blinder 1974, pp. 883–890]

---

To get back the old unnormalised behaviour, add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}
```

to your preamble.

---

If you want to get rid of the page prefix "p."/"pp." now, you may want to consider keeping the `\mknormrange`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

instead of just `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`.

---

Note that the `pages` format does not use `\mknormrange` because its contents are already prenormalised by Biber.